# How to model when to buy and sell a stock?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio

Given a set of historical data and volatility of price in each day, how is it possible to determine a price to purchase a stock at each day? For example, I want to find a price like $125 and receive a signal to purchase a stock tomorrow.
I am sorry if this question is simple, my background is not in Finance, and if you recommend some references and keywords, I would be thankful.

Comment: I voted to close this. It is neither clear what is asked (in my opinion), nor can you expect that a model will be able to provide a signal to purchase a stock tomorrow.